# lsusb command not found

Tags: usb

I've installed Ubuntu on an external drive and it don't see my USB dongle. I am a complete novice with things Ubuntu.

After doing some digging I found that step 1 was to run `lsusb`. But that set of instructions doesn't say what to do it `lsusb` command is not found.

Can I use my Windows Internet to download files, then boot in Ubuntu and copy and install stuff, or is ntfs a problem.  And then what command lines to use.  Maybe its to big a problem for a beginner and should find another disk from another magazine.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install usbutils
```

and got back

```
Reading package lists... done   
Building dependancy tree   
Reading state information... done  
usbutils is already the newest version   
0 upgraded,  0 newly installed,  0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

it is still telling me command not found

Comment: What is output of `locate lsusb`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy usbutils`

Answer (score 44):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install usbutils
```

Comment: Ubuntu always has `lsusb` installed. The question means that there is some problem or it is not Ubuntu.

Comment: Its saucy salamanda   and i have other problems too, I remember something about corrupted files

Comment: Thanks Ravan,  A B,  and Pilot6   for the input,  I havnt solved the problem yet, but your advice has been a good start.  I get the feeling that if I can get my hotspot connection working,  this issue may be solved more easily

Comment: there is also a brew package for osx for this now too:
https://github.com/jlhonora/homebrew-lsusb